# google sheet, importxml function shows a blo

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Tried this google sheet function - didnt work

```
=importxml(D32, "//h2[@id='currentMinimumCapitalRequirement']")
```

Result: blank.
What i want: 100,244 ETH
website: https://nexustracker.io/capital_pool

[image: inspect]

Any idea why? been at it for hours!

Comment: The number comes from a xhr: https://nexustracker.io/minimum_capital_requirement

Answer (score 0):

the values you want to import are not there. you can check this by disabling JavaScript for that site. Google Shhets is not able to read JS content. all you can scrape is what you see on picture:

[image]

[image]